# Chrome Extension: XMLHttpRequest canceled (status == 0)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I try to load a json file from a server with `XMLHttpRequest`.
But I only get `status==0` and the chrome dev console says: "(canceled)"

I can reproduce this with this (simplified) code:

```
var httpReq = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
httpReq.onreadystatechange = function(data) { 
  if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
    alert(httpReq.status);
  }                
}                    
httpReq.open("GET", "http://dl.dropbox.com/[...]/data.json");
httpReq.send(null);
```

This code stops working, as it is in the extension context.
The same function is also used to load files from an other server (also crossdomain), without any problem.

Here is the manifest part:

```
"permissions": [ "http://theOtherWorkingServer.com/*", "http://dl.dropbox.com/*", "https://dl.dropbox.com/*" ],
```

I've read a lot about this problem, but found no working solution.
(The main page is not reloading and also not redirected at this time)

Any suggestions??

Comment: chrome version is 27.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is a sign that a redirect was performed, to an URL which does not match any of your declared permissions.
To verify my statement, add the `*://*/*` or `<all_urls>` permission to the manifest file, and you will notice that the request completes successfully.

To determine which redirects are followed, follow the following steps:

1. Open the developer tools, go to the Network tab.
2. Paste the URL in the omnibox, and hit enter
3. Read the URLs in the developer tools.

[image]

As you can see in the previous picture, `dl.dropbox.com` actually redirects to `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`. This domain has to be added to the permission section of your manifest file, to fix the problem:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://theOtherWorkingServer.com/*",
    "*://dl.dropbox.com/*",
    "*://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/*"
],
```

(the the wildcard at the scheme matches `http` and `https` - see [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html))

Comment: I didn't see that redirect...

Now it works perfect!
Thanks Rob W !

Comment: I added `*://*/*` to permissions and am still getting status 0, is there anything else that can cause this?

Comment: @mheiber Don't forget to reload the extension and close+reopen the tab to enforce the new permissions.