# Why is this ajax request returning an status code of 0 instead of 200?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple function for making an ajax request,
which I use to open a local json file:

```
ajaxRequest: function(url, callback) {
    var xmlHTTP= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if(xmlHTTP.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            // success code
            // 0 for Google Chrome
            // 200 for Android webview
            // 200 in jQuery
            if(xmlHTTP.status === 0 ) {
                callback(xmlHTTP.responseText);
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHTTP.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHTTP.send();
}
```

This is how I implement it:

```
ajaxRequest("json/1.json", function(response) {

});
```

My problem is with the status code.

If I test with Google Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 and the web security disabled,
the success code is 0, but if I use the jQuery ajax function, like this:

```
$.get( "json/1.json", function( data ) {

});
```

the success code is 200.

I'm doing a mobile app (hybrid), and in the Android webview, with my vanilla javascript function,
the status code returned is 200 (like jquery), not 0.

So, how can I alway get a status code of 200 with my vanilla javascript function, like jquery does?

Comment: Status 0 is Cancelled. This seems like it could be caused by CORS permissions. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104982/chrome-extension-xmlhttprequest-canceled-status-0) for potential causes.

Comment: thanks @Phylogenesis, I'm starting chrome with this flag: --disable-web-security and the onreadystatechange returns the json properly with the status code 0

Comment: when developing hybrid apps, I use these arguments: --disable-web-security --allow-access-from-files --allow-file-access and never a problem, you could give it a shot