# XMLHttpRequest status 0 in click event handler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension to take advantage of an API we have written. The problem I'm having is that the popup.html has a login form, and when the submit button is pressed it calls the necessary authentication code, which involves making a couple of XMLHttpRequests to the API server.

The code is as follows:

**authenticate.js**

```
function authenticate(username, password)
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "<api-server>/challenge?username=dummyusername", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      alert(xhr.status);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}

/*Gets the username and password textboxes from popup.html and passes their values on to authenticate()*/
function getCredentials()
{
  authenticate("test", "test");
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
  if (submitBtn != null) {
    submitBtn.onclick = getCredentials;
  }
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="usernameTxt"><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="passwordTxt"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <script src="authenticate.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "description": "Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "<api-server>"
  ]
}
```

If, however, I replace:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
  if (submitBtn != null) {
    submitBtn.onclick = getCredentials;
  }
});
```

with:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  getCredentials();
});
```

it does the right thing, which leads me to believe it's to do with the fact that it's being called from a click event handler and perhaps somehow the permissions haven't been extended to the button.

I saw this post ([Chrome Extension: XMLHttpRequest canceled (status == 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104982/chrome-extension-xmlhttprequest-canceled-status-0)) and added `"<all_urls>"` to permissions and that has made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancel the click so the form does not submit.

```
document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    getCredentials();
});
```

Comment: What click are you reffering to in the event "DOMContentLoaded"?

Comment: Now, that is what I meant... Morning coffee has not kicked in.

Comment: Thanks, this suggestion worked even though I know you accidentally put in the wrong code initially. How come you have to cancel the click?

Comment: Because the form submits and the page refreshes and kills the Ajax call.

Comment: The initial problem is actually trying to use `onclick` attribute, which is [forbidden by the extension CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution). Changing to `addEventListener` is the most important part.

Comment: It wasn't inline javascript in the first place, and I tried changing it to `addEventListener` without cancelling the click and that didn't work either. epascarello made me realise the problem was because of the page refreshing, so I actually realised I could just solve this by changing the type of submitBtn to button instead of submit. I left the javascript the same and now it works.